# Romance manhwa where the female lead regresses for the 3rd time to childhood and chooses a different husband

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

In it the female lead is regressed for the 3rd time to when she is a child where she chooses a different husband from the last time. She has tried to escape with a lover but both times hunted and kill mercilessly.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[The Broken Ring: This Marriage Will Fail Anyway](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5o3xoq1/the-broken-ring-this-marriage-will-fail-anyway)***...?

> When six-year-old Inés laid eyes on the handsome heir to House Escalante, she promptly made the boy her fiancé. Since noble men are all the same, she figured she might as well choose a pretty one. But Lord Cárcel isn't ready for this sort of commitment just yet, and he spends the next decade and a half avoiding the marriage at all costs! Luckily, that's no trouble for Inés, as this marriage failing is exactly what she wants. In fact, he has her blessing to sow his wild oats as long as he stays out of her business. Unfortunately, being a playboy isn't as fun when your fiancée gives you permission. And doesn't this mean she's cheating on him too? Now, Cárcel is determined to change Inés' mind about him and prove he can be the husband she's always wanted.

As a young girl, the female lead turned down a marriage proposal from the crown prince, choosing to marry a lord instead, because he had a pretty face.

> [image]

It's later revealed that she's in a time loop of some sort, and that in a previous loop, she married the prince and had a series of miscarriages, for which she was blamed. The cause of the miscarriages were STDs that she caught from the prince as a result of his infidelity, and she ultimately took her own life with a rifle.

> [image]

In a subsequent loop, she ran away with a portrait artist's assistant, but after spending a few years together, he was shot and killed in front of her, and she later committed suicide again.

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot bro.

Comment: @Flaw - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.